# Putting all information of list in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

Hi guys I'm new in programming and Stackoverflow and English is my second language if I have some mistakes , forgive me. I'm writing code for my teacher about a list which you get information name , ID number , and name. My problem is that at the end of loop I don't know how to make a list of All information .
that's my code :

```
loopnumber = int(input("please enter your number of people"))
for i in range (loopnumber) :

    IDnumber = input("please enter your ID number.")
    while len(IDnumber) != 10 :
        IDnumber = input("please try again.")

    name = input("please enter your name.")

    age = int(input("please enter your age."))
    while age <= 0 :
        age = int(input(" please try Again."))

    listpeople = [IDnumber, name, age ]
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't make a list at the end.  You create empty lists at the beginning, and you `.append` your new information to those empty lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a list then keep `append`ing your information as a list itself.

```py
# start with the empty list
listpeople = []

loopnumber = int(input("please enter your number of people"))

for i in range (loopnumber) :
    IDnumber = input("please enter your ID number.")
    while len(IDnumber) != 10 :
        IDnumber = input("please try again.")

    name = input("please enter your name.")

    age = int(input("please enter your age."))
    while age <= 0 :
        age = int(input(" please try Again."))

    # put all the data you have in a list
    individual_details = [IDnumber, name, age]

    # append the personal_details list to the parent list aka listpeople
    listpeople.append(individual_details)
```

[A diagram of the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElV4S.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty list of people

```py
listPeople = []
```

At the end of the `for` loop, append the list of `IDnumber`, `name` and `age` to the `listPeople` list

```py
listPeople = []

loopnumber = int(input("please enter your number of people: "))

for i in range(loopnumber):
    IDnumber = input("please enter your ID number: ")
    while len(IDnumber) != 10:
        IDnumber = input("please try again: ")

    name = input("please enter your name: ")

    age = int(input("please enter your age: "))
    while age <= 0:
        age = int(input(" please try Again: "))

    listPeople.append([IDnumber, name, age])

print(listPeople)
```

Output:

```
please enter your number of people: 2
please enter your ID number: 1111111111
please enter your name: geeky
please enter your age: 19
please enter your ID number: 2222222222
please enter your name: quentin
please enter your age: 19
[['1111111111', 'geeky', 19], ['2222222222', 'quentin', 19]]
```

Comment: hi thanks a lot but when I print the list at the end , it shows the last information one  it doesn't show all what can I do for all ?

Comment: @TohidSG, I have modified my code to take input properly, and I have included the output as well, can you show your output too?

Comment: thanks a lot it finally worked . you were the first person who answered my question. thanks a lot. that was my pleasure.

Answer (score -1):

```py
listpeople = [] 
loopnumber = int(input("please enter your number of people"))
for i in range (loopnumber) :

    IDnumber = input("please enter your ID number.")
    while len(IDnumber) != 10 :
        IDnumber = input("please try again.")

    name = input("please enter your name.")

    age = int(input("please enter your age."))
    while age <= 0 :
        age = int(input(" please try Again."))

    personal_details = [IDnumber, name, age] # Rename this variable to personal_details or personal_info because it holds each person's information 
    listpeople.append(personal_details)
```

Comment: hello thanks you  when I print the list at the end , it shows the last one it doesn't show all what information .what do I do for 
 showing all ?